# unicode characters not showing properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I crawled a set of sites and extracted different strings with unicode encoded characters such as 'Best places to eat in D\xfcsseldorf'. I have them stored as showed in a PostgreSQL database. When I retrieve strings that the mentioned earlier from Database and do:

```
name = string_retrieved_from_database
print name
```

outputs as unicode u'Best places to eat in D\xfcsseldorf'. I want to display the string as it should be: 'Best places to eat in Düsseldorf'. How can I do that.

Comment: What are the actual bytes you got back from crawling the sites?  Chances are, your error was introduced at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you get output when you *print* the variable, instead of just displaying it interactively?  You should never get the `u'...'` display when using `print`:

```
>>> x = b"Best places to eat in D\xfcsseldorf"
>>> x.decode('latin-1')
u'Best places to eat in D\xfcsseldorf'
>>> print x.decode('latin-1')
Best places to eat in Düsseldorf
```

If you're getting the backslash and so forth in the actual string, then it's possible something went wrong at the encoding stage (e.g., literal backslashes were written into the text).  In that case you may want to look at the "unicode-escape" codec:

```
>>> x = b"Best places to eat in D\\xfcsseldorf"
>>> print x
Best places to eat in D\xfcsseldorf
>>> print x.decode('unicode-escape')
Best places to eat in Düsseldorf
```

Comment: yes, actually my problem was storing them directly to database without the proper handling, x.decode('unicode-escape') worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deal with the encodings as quickly as possible.  The best thing is to read the HTML page, decode the byte strings you get into Unicode, and then store the strings as Unicode in the database, or at least in a uniform encoding like UTF8.

If you need help with the details, [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain](http://bit.ly/unipain) has them all.