# Django upload and handle CSV file with right encoding

Tags: python, django

I try to upload and handle a CSV file in my Django project, but I get an encoding error, the CSV file is created on a mac with excel..

```
reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['file'].read().splitlines(), delimiter=";")
    if withheader:
        reader.next()

data = [[field.decode('utf-8') for field in row] for row in reader]
```

With this code example i get an error: http://puu.sh/1VmXc

If I use latin-1 decode i get an other "error"..

```
data = [[field.decode('latin-1') for field in row] for row in reader]
```

the result is: v¾gmontere   and the result should be: vægmontere

Anyone know what to do? .. i have tried a lot!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270703/unicode-characters-not-showing-properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The Python 2 `csv` module comes with lots of unicode hassle. [Try `unicodecsv` instead](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) or use Python 3.
2. Excel on Mac exports to CSV with broken encoding. Don't use it, use something useful like LibreOffice instead (has a much better CSV export with options).
3. When handling user files: either make sure files are consistently encoded in UTF-8 and only decode to UTF-8 (recommended) or use an encoding detection library like [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

Comment: Ohh god ... It's seems to be the MS Excel on mac that was the problem ... thanks alot!